# How to set a different link in each cell in a range?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm programming a Macro in VB for Excel 2013 that search for coincidences in different worksheets, and add a link to the cells that match.

I'm havin torubles to insert the link in the cell, since the link must be different for a range of cells, I need help here.

Here is my code

```
Dim bufferDetails As String
Dim tmpCell As String
Dim spot As String
Dim cell As Variant
Dim cellSpots As Variant

For Each cell In Worksheets("MMS-Locations").Range("D2:D1833")
    If (cell.Value2 = "NULL") Then
        cell.Value2 = "NULL"
    Else
        tmpCell = cell.Text
        'A62
        If (Left(tmpCell, 3) = "A62") Then
            spot = spotName(tmpCell)
            For Each cellSpots In Worksheets("DetailedMap").Range("G60:CF123")
                If (cellSpots.Value2 = spot) Then
                    For Each linkToSpot In Worksheets("MMS-Locations").Range("H2:H1833")
                        Worksheets("MMS-Locations").Hyperlinks.Add _
                            Anchor:=Range(linkToSpot), _
                            Address:="http://example.microsoft.com", _
                            ScreenTip:="Microsoft Web Site", _
                            TextToDisplay:="Microsoft"

                    Next linkToSpot
                    Debug.Print ("Encontrado " + cellSpots)
                End If
            Next cellSpots
        End If 
    End If
Next cell

End Sub

Function spotName(fullName As String) As String

Dim realSpot As String
Dim lenght As Integer

lenght = Len(fullName) - 3
realSpot = Right(fullName, lenght)

spotName = realSpot

End Function
```

As I was thinking the linkToSpot variable contains the actual cell in the range, so I can move my selection of the sell, but my code fails in there with this error:

Error in the Range method of the '_Global' object,

Comment: Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174723/run-time-error-1004-method-range-of-object-global-failed

Comment: Which line? It should be `Anchor:=linkToSpot`.

Comment: If you start off at the top with `Dim linkToSpot as Range`, then you should (I think) just be able to do `...Anchor:=linkToSpot, _ ...`.  But you may even be able to do that now, without declaring `linkToSpot as Range`, but it's best practice to always declare your variables.  OR, if you want (for whatever reason) to keep it with `Range()`, do this instead: `Anchor:=Range(linkToSpot.Address), _ ...`.

Comment: @BruceWayne thanks, this worked, but now this hole block `Worksheets("MMS-Locations").Hyperlinks.Add _
                                Anchor:=Range(linkToSpot.Adress), _
                                Address:="http://example.microsoft.com", _
                                ScreenTip:="Microsoft Web Site", _
                                TextToDisplay:="Microsoft"`
Shows an error "Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method"

Comment: And Even by adding the variable at the top, shows the same error as before

Comment: With just `Anchor:=Range(linkToSpot)` make sure to add the worksheet `linkToSpot`'s range is coming from. I.e. `Anchor = Worksheets("MMS-Locations").Range(linkToSpot.Address)`.  Also while you're troubleshooting, I'd put that whole thing on one line.  Does this still throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, here is what I use to convert a phone number to an email for texting..setting it as a hyperlink in the current cell.

```
ActiveCell.Value = myNumbr 
Set myRange = ActiveCell 
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=myRange, Address:="mailto:" & myRange.Value, TextToDisplay:=myRange.Value`
```

Keep your code simple to start with, until you find a working script, then add other items. Make good use of the F8 key to step through your code to find out exactly where an error occurs.