# Excel VBA autofill based on dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

Please can you help with the below; I have an increasing list of staff listed in A1, and I want my formulas in E1, F1, G1, etc. to be autofilled and not static like I have now.

I have the below but its throwing up the error: Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

My vba code;

```
Sub AutoFill()

    Dim RowCount As Variant

    RowCount = Range(("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    Range("E1").Select ' Default formula's in E1
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(RowCount - 1), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

What am I missing, i'm stumped and have been since yesterday...

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run-time error '1004' : Method 'Range' of object'\_Global' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174723/run-time-error-1004-method-range-of-object-global-failed)

Comment: `Range(RowCount - 1)` this is just a number, not a range, need something like `Range("A1:A" & RowCount - 1)`

Answer (score 2):

The [Range.FillDown method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.filldown) method may be easier to code.

```
Sub DynAutoFill()

    Dim lastRow As long

    lastRow = cells(rows.count, "A").end(xlup).row  'should -1 be added here?
    Range(cells(1, "E"), cells(lastRow, "E")).filldown

End Sub
```

FillDown can easily handle multiple columns.

```
Sub DynAutoFill()

    Dim lastRow As long

    lastRow = cells(rows.count, "A").end(xlup).row  'should -1 be added here?
    Range(cells(1, "E"), cells(lastRow, "G")).filldown

End Sub
```

Your own code needs the entire range as the destination.

```
Sub DynAutoFill()

    Dim RowCount As Variant

    RowCount = Range(("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    Range("E1").AutoFill Destination:=Range(cells(1, "E", cells(RowCount - 1, "E")), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

I wouldn't use a reserved word for the name of the sub procedure.

Comment: user10781941 - you're amazing!  I have one question, my manager has now got data and a 'sexy border' in the first few rows.   Can I start the code from say A7 instead of A1?

Comment: Should be as simple as `Range(cells(7, "E"), cells(lastRow, "E")).filldown` with your seeded formula in E7.